# Flutter imports aren't recognized

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, import

So, I am a newbie at flutter. I switced to flutter beta channel and used flutter upgrade.

```
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  
  void main() {
    runApp(MyApp());
  }
  
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Netflix UI',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(),
      );
    }
  }
```

So the package here isn't recognized. It worked first time. But due to an unfortunate accident my files got erased and that I want to rebuild it, I can't because the imports are not recognized. I have restarted android studio for three times now and even restarted my laptop. I have a deadline to meet. Please, someone help. T.T

Comment: why do you switch to beta version, chechk flutter stable version

Comment: and run `flutter pub get` command

Comment: @RafiaChy I noticed that you are yet to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/684852) to your questions, note that this is one of the main features of the platform, not doing so will discourage users from answering your questions.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have Flutter listed in your dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

And also ensure you've fetched packages (using `flutter pub get` or the button that appears when you have the `pubspec.yaml` file open).

Comment: I checked that and it was there. I needed to Pub get and Pub Upgrade. And it worked! (*-*)/`

Answer (score 1):

**Hey Rafia!**

First Add dependency then hit `-pub get`

after that go to your `main.dart` and import the package.

it would work!

Comment: Thanks! I also needed pug upgrade. And it worked! Yay.